# How do I add a Cname for 'www' to point to my actual domain in Google Cloud DNS?

Tags: google-cloud-dns

My domain without "www" works fine.  My A record points to the ip address and works with SSL just fine.  I have tried to add CNAME www point to @ but that does not seem to work in Google Cloud DNS.  If I point my www CNAME to the domain without "www" then I get a not protected warning when trying to access it.  How do I get "www" to work in Cloud DNS.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [so] is for programming questions. [sf] would be better places for questions like this.

Answer (score 0):

The second way you used to create the cname is the correct.
Regarding the SSL issue. If I am understanding properly, seems like the SSL certificate you have is only covering the "example.com" domain.
Since "www.example.com" is a subdomain of "example.com" (at the end of the day are different domains) you need to have another SSL certificate for [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), that way you will avoid the not protected warning.
Or you could have a single SSL cert with multiple domains (covering "example.com" and "www.example.com").